# How to achieve inner join using Java SparkSql

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two datasets as

DATASET1

```
+-------+--------------------+  
|     id|                name|  
+-------+--------------------+  
|S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|  
|S703401|Christopher J Mat...|  
|S703401|      Frank E LaSota|    
|S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|  
|S703401|Anthony L Locricchio|  
|S703401|         Jason Monte|  
+-------+--------------------+
```

DATASET2

```
+-------+------+  
|     id|   nic|  
+-------+------+    
|S703401|  RC82|  
|S703401|    NA|  
|S703401|   FL3|  
|S703401|  RC82|  
|S703401|    NA|  
|S703401|JM2080|  
+-------+------+
```

and i want to join them on id so that i can have output as

```
+-------+--------------------+-----------+  
|     id|                name|       nic |   
+-------+--------------------+-----------+  
|S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|       RC82|  
|S703401|Christopher J Mat...|         NA|  
|S703401|      Frank E LaSota|        FL3|  
|S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|       RC82|  
|S703401|Anthony L Locricchio|         NA|  
|S703401|         Jason Monte|     JM2080|  
+-------+--------------------+-----------+
```

I am using java spark  **Dataset  joined = dataset1.join(dataset2,"id");**   but them i am getting cartesian product for all the rows like

```
+-------+--------------------+------+  
|     id |                 name|   nic|  
+-------+--------------------+------+  
|S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|JM2080|  
|S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|    NA|  
|S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|  RC82|  
|S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|   FL3|  
|S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|    NA|  
|S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|  RC82|  
|S703401|Christopher J Mat...|JM2080|  
|S703401|Christopher J Mat...|    NA|  
|S703401|Christopher J Mat...|  RC82|  
|S703401|Christopher J Mat...|   FL3|  
|S703401|Christopher J Mat...|    NA|  
|S703401|Christopher J Mat...|  RC82|  
|S703401|      Frank E LaSota|JM2080|  
|S703401|      Frank E LaSota|    NA|  
|S703401|      Frank E LaSota|  RC82|  
|S703401|      Frank E LaSota|   FL3|  
|S703401|      Frank E LaSota|    NA|  
|S703401|      Frank E LaSota|  RC82|  
|S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|JM2080|  
|S703401|      Ryan P Cassidy|    NA|  
+-------+--------------------+------+
```

So what am i missing here?

Comment: you have multiple same id in both datasets so it is obvious that you will get many to many relation. Do you have any logic on which you can decide your desire output?

Comment: i want to add nic values in dataset1 where dataset1.id = dataset2.id, so i can get 6 output only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use ,`monotonically_increasing_id` function to generate `rowId`. It gives random number which will fail your `join` logic. So go with `row_number` function that will give you correct `rowId` in all your cases.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

scala> df.show()
+-------+------------------+
|     id|              name|
+-------+------------------+
|S703401|      RyanPCassidy|
|S703401|ChristopherJMat...|
|S703401|      FrankELaSota|
|S703401|      RyanPCassidy|
|S703401|AnthonyLLocricchio|
|S703401|        JasonMonte|
+-------+------------------+


scala> df1.show()
+-------+------+
|     id|   nic|
+-------+------+
|S703401|  RC82|
|S703401|    NA|
|S703401|   FL3|
|S703401|  RC82|
|S703401|    NA|
|S703401|JM2080|
+-------+------+


scala> val w = Window.partitionBy(col("id")).orderBy(lit(1))

scala> df.withColumn("rw", row_number.over(w))
         .join(df1.withColumn("rw", row_number.over(w)), List("id", "rw"),"left")
         .drop("rw")
         .show(false)
+-------+------------------+------+
|id     |name              |nic   |
+-------+------------------+------+
|S703401|RyanPCassidy      |RC82  |
|S703401|ChristopherJMat...|NA    |
|S703401|FrankELaSota      |FL3   |
|S703401|RyanPCassidy      |RC82  |
|S703401|AnthonyLLocricchio|NA    |
|S703401|JasonMonte        |JM2080|
+-------+------------------+------+
```